# How to get SSIS folder using registry

Tags: ssis, windows-installer, registry, installshield

I am working on building installer using InstallShield Basic MSI and I need to copy some files into SSIS folder.

Example location is: *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn*

The problem is depending on what version is installed folder could be 90/100/110/120.

I searched the web but could find reliable way to find where I can find this. 
There should be somewhere in registry but having hard time to find it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**Question:** How to find DTS folder location using registry?

Comment: And what if someone has SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 *and* 2014 installed - which folder should be returned?

Comment: I need to find universal solution for all the versions, that's the question. How to get folder using registry.